# Next.js useChat hook with a custom endpoint

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am trying to implement a chatbot using useChat hook from next.js. Here is the link the SDK
https://sdk.vercel.ai/docs/api-reference/use-chat

All the examples that I have found is using default route of api/chat on the same project but I need to use this with external API which I call by passing in authentication token to get StreamingTextResponse. Can I use these hook or not? If yes, how do I pass in the external API in there.

If I cannot use this, what is the best way to stream content in next.js for a chatbot. Any examples will be great

Comment: Following the same link you provided it mentions the options object that you can provide, can't you pass `{ api: 'url.of.your.api' }` as a parameter for `useChat()`?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
"use client";
import { useChat } from "ai/react";

export default function Chat() {

const options = {
 api: "http://your-api-url.com"
};

const { messages, input, handleInputChange, handleSubmit } = useChat(options);
```